# $f_\infty(t)=g_\infty(t)$ a.e?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$  two uniformly integrable sequences such that:
$$
\qquad\forall n\geq 1~:~ f_n(t)=g_n(t)~~ \text{ a.e.}\tag1
$$
$$
\qquad f_n\underset{n}{\to} f_\infty\text{ weakly in } L^1 \tag2
$$
and for all subsequence $\{g_{n_i}\}$ of $\{g_n\}$ we have
$$
\qquad\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{g_{n_i}(t)}\underset{m}{\to} g_\infty(t) \text{ a.e.} \tag3
$$
Can we say that $f_\infty(t)=g_\infty(t) \text{ a.e}$?

**My effort:**

Since $\{g_n\}$ is U.I then there exists a subsequence $\{g_{n_i}\}$ of $\{g_n\}$ such that weakly convergence in $L^1$ . It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that
$$
\qquad g_{n_i}\underset{i}{\to} f_\infty\text{ weakly in } L^1 
$$
then for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$
$$
\lim_i \int_A g_{n_i} \,d\mu=\int_A f_\infty \,d\mu
$$
then, by Cesàro lemma, we have

$$
\lim_m\int_A \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m g_{n_i} \,d\mu=\int_A f_\infty \, d\mu
$$

The sequence  $\{s_m\}$,  defined by $s_m:=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m g_{n_i}$, is uniformly integrable and converge weakly to $g_\infty$ then
$$
\lim_m\int_A s_m \, d\mu=\int_A g_\infty \, d\mu\qquad\forall A\in\mathcal{A}
$$
then
$$
\int_A f_\infty \, d\mu=\int_A g_\infty \, d\mu\qquad\forall A \in \mathcal{A}
$$
then $f_\infty(t)=g_\infty(t) \text{ a.e.}$

Is what I wrote correct? If not, please help.